# IS there any way we can add range in hyperparameter tuning of Decision Tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, machine-learning-model, data-science-model, hyperparameter-tuning

For example,

```
           "min_samples_leaf":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
           'criterion':['gini','entropy'],
            "max_features":["auto","log2","sqrt",None],
           "max_leaf_nodes":[None,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90] }
```

but i want to add range of 1 to 100 in max deapth. is there any way i can do it?
Like shown below....

```
parameters={"max_depth" : range(1,100), ??????????
           "min_samples_leaf":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
           'criterion':['gini','entropy'],
            "max_features":["auto","log2","sqrt",None],
           "max_leaf_nodes":[None,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, for example, use `"max_depth": np.arange(1, 101, 1)` which gives

```
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
        14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
        27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,
        40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,
        53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,
        66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,
        79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,
        92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100])
```

as a value range.

Comment: Thank you soo much .

Comment: @VihaanShah if your question has been answered, please accept the answer. Otherwise the question will keep floating around and popping up as still requiring an answer.

Comment: I am new to this i dont know how to accept it. PLs guide. Thank you

Comment: Ok i guess i accpeted . The correct button below the upvote,right?

Comment: @VihaanShah perfect, you did indeed accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the site! You can use `list(range(1,100))` to get what you want. However, questions like this (how to achieve something in Python) are more suitable for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). The community here focuses on data science related questions, as the name suggests.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Yes will be more active on stackoverflow. Thank you.